# Search function with list of text values fails

Tags: excel

[I use formula =SEARCH({"N.","No.","#"},D5) and it fails if doesn't fit first option "N." how can I fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRC8G.jpg)

Comment: check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803944/excel-searching-for-multiple-terms-in-a-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `=SEARCH({"N.","No.","#"},D5)` formula when you will see how the formula calculates the result using **Evaluate Formula**, you'll notice

[image]

evaluates to

[image]

That means formula is searching only for `"N."`

Therefore to search for the existence of `"N.","No.","#"` in a cell, number of approaches are available like:

***1.*** `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"N.","No.","#"},D5)),1,"")`

This formula will give `1` if any of the string in the cell exists.

***2.*** `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(find_text,D5)))>0`

This formula will give `TRUE` if any of the three string exists else `FASLE`.