# Count or Sum (?) items in a single cell that match criteria from a list in Excel

Tags: excel, search, text, cell

I have a single cell that is the output of a survey, that contains items selected from a list of 20 possible items.

ie.
Original possible selections:

Ape, Blue, Cat, Red, Dog, Yellow, Pig, Purple, Zebra

User is asked to "select all of the animals," from the list of possible selections. The output places all of the items they've identified into a single cell, separated by commas.
A new row is created for each survey entry.

ie.

| User 1 | "Ape, Cat, Pig, Purple" |

| User 2 | "Cat, Red, Dog, Pig, Zebra" |

| User 3 | "Ape, Cat, Dog, Pig, Zebra" |
etc...

I have a table with all of the animals and colors, with defined ranges.

ie. animals = A1:A5, and colours = B1:B4

I need to "score" the cell for each user, in a new cell. Where the score value is the count of the number of correctly identified items each counts as 1 point.

ie.

| User 1 | "Ape, Cat, Pig, Purple" | 3 |

| User 2 | "Cat, Red, Dog, Pig, Zebra" | 4 |

| User 3 | "Ape, Cat, Dog, Pig, Zebra" | 5 |

What would the formula need to be for that score cell for each row?

I found a previous thread, that seems to point in the right direction, 
[Excel: Searching for multiple terms in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803944/excel-searching-for-multiple-terms-in-a-cell)
But this only checks for the *existence* of any of the items in a cell from a list and returns a true or false

Thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: Seems like you should also be subtracting 1 for each *wrong* item, or you could get perfect scores by always selecting all items?

Comment: Indeed! I figured once I had the first part, I could figure out the rest... which I did, btw, using the answer I marked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNTIF with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2,"*" & $A$1:$A$5 & "*"))
```

Which also has the limitation of the amimals not being a sub-string, like `Ant` and `Ant-Eater`

[image]

---

If sub-strings are a problem then use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", " & $A$1:$A$5 & ", ",", " & D2 & ", "))))
```

This will make a complete match between the commas.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked as desired.

I further extended it, btw, to include subtracting the incorrectly selected colours, using the following formula:

`(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2,"*" & $A$1:$A$5 & "*"))) - (SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2,"*" & $B$1:$B$4 & "*"))`

Answer (score 0):

The formula shown is entered in D3 (an array formula, so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and filled down to D5

A3:A6 is a named range "animals"

Note this is only reliable if none of your terms are sub-strings of another term.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like to use the formulas above, which are very efficient and most ideal, a simpler but longer way would be as follows:

select the animals--> Data--> Text to Columns, and split them into columns with the separator being a comma

Once this is done, do a countif on each column, and it will total it up for you. You will need to do 20 countifs though, so it is far from ideal
IE

```
=countifs(column which it could be in],[no.1 animal])+
countifs(column which it could be in],[no.2 animal])+...
countifs(column which it could be in],[no.20 animal])
```

This is easy to see how it works and if you receive more answers you will have to split them out again